# User-friendly string struct and utility function - upated version

Tags: c, strings

### Updated previously posted string struct and utility functions

Previous link: [User-friendly string struct and utility functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269062/user-friendly-string-struct-and-utility-functions/)

##### What is updated ?

- typedef of sstring is a major update. previously, users had to do sstring var; and then var._str = value, But now, users can do sstring var = "Value";
- Buffer overflows have been fixed
- major bugs and features have been improved and fixed
- All functions now have error checking methods
- conversion from c-style array strings to sstrings and vice-versa is now easily possible through sstr2cstr() and cstr2sstr() functions!
- conversion from string to number [double/float/int] type is easily possible. It has some unique things such as it can tell if the string is a number, if an error has occured and returns the actual number!
- Sstrinputpass() introduces new type of password input method!
- All functions have slight improvements

Any suggestions, bug-report or feedbacks are Happily Welcomed!

##### - Files -

sstring.h

```c
#ifndef SSTRING_H_DEFINED
//stdbool for sstrnum typedef
#include<stdbool.h>
#define SSTRING_H_DEFINED
//define the maximum char limit here
#define GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT 400

#define NO_ERR -1
#define GMCL_CORRUPT -10
#define INVALID_ARGS -11
#define GMCL_ERR -12

typedef struct{
    double _num;
    bool is_num;
    int _err;
}sstrnum;

typedef char * sstring;

typedef struct{
    char _str[GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT];
    int _err;
}sstrfunc;

typedef struct{
    char _char;
    int _err;
}charfunc;

typedef sstrfunc sstrfuncerr;

void nullify(char * _Buff,int _count);
sstrnum sstr2num(sstring _str);
sstrfunc cstr2sstr(char * _Buff);
int sstr2cstr(sstring _sstr,char * _Cstr,size_t _upto);
sstrfunc sstrappend(sstring _var1,sstring _var2);
sstrfunc sstrinput();
ssize_t sstrfind(size_t init,sstring _str,sstring _find);
size_t sstrlen(sstring _str);
sstrfunc ssetchar(sstring _str,ssize_t _pos,char _ch);
sstrfunc ssubstr(sstring _str,int _pos,size_t _len);
charfunc sgetchar(sstring _str,ssize_t _pos);
sstrfunc sstrinputpass(sstring show);
void showerrs();

#endif
```

sstring.c

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "sstring.h"
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

/*
A Big Note To the ones saying dont return Local Variable Adresses

Below functions dont return any local variable addresses
to prove it, call the functions MULTIPLE times  -> you will see yourself

They return a typedef of strfunc which contains the string in array format
when the user does [functionname]([parameters])._str; the str array value is sent to the pointer
so no issue will be created! :D

*/


size_t sstrlen(sstring _str){
    //just as support for sstrings
    // all functions included are better!
    return strlen(_str);
}

bool isGMCLCorrupt(){
    //checks if global max char limit is corrupted
    if(GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT<=0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

sstrfunc cstr2sstr(char * _Buff){
    sstrfunc _null;
    nullify(_null._str,GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT);
    _null._err = NO_ERR;
    if(isGMCLCorrupt()){
        _null._err = GMCL_CORRUPT;
        return _null;
    }
    if(strlen(_Buff)>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT){
        _null._err = GMCL_ERR;
        return _null;
    }
    //blank string
    if(strlen(_Buff)==0){
        return _null;
    }
    sstrfunc _ret;
    strncpy(_ret._str,_Buff,strlen(_Buff));
    _ret._err = NO_ERR;
    return _ret;
}

int sstr2cstr(sstring _sstr,char * _Cstr,size_t _upto){
    
    //first null out the _Cstr upto given length
    nullify(_Cstr,_upto);
    
    if(isGMCLCorrupt()){
        return GMCL_CORRUPT;
    }
    if(sstrlen(_sstr)>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT){
        return GMCL_ERR;
    }
    
    //blank string
    if(sstrlen(_sstr)==0){
        return NO_ERR;
    }
    
    strncpy(_Cstr,_sstr,_upto);
    return NO_ERR;
}

sstrnum sstr2num(sstring _str){
    char cchar;
    int minus = 1;
    int plus=0;
    sstrnum _return;
    int pointplace=0;
    _return._err = NO_ERR;
    _return.is_num = true;
    if(isGMCLCorrupt()){
        _return._err = GMCL_CORRUPT;
        _return._num = 0;
        _return.is_num = false;
        return _return;
    }else if(sstrlen(_str)>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT){
        _return._err = GMCL_ERR;
        _return._num = 0;
        _return.is_num = false;
        return _return;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<sstrlen(_str);i++){
        cchar = _str[i];
        //if non integer found
        if(cchar<'0'||cchar>'9'){
            if(cchar=='-'&&i==0){
                minus = -1;
            }else if(cchar=='-'&&i>0){
                _return._num = 0;
                _return.is_num = false;
                _return._err = NO_ERR;
                return _return;
            }else if(cchar=='.'&&pointplace==0){
                pointplace+=1;
            }else if(cchar=='.'&&!(pointplace==0)){
                _return._num = 0;
                _return.is_num = false;
                _return._err = NO_ERR;
                return _return;
            }else if(cchar=='+'&&plus==0){
                plus=1;
            }else if(cchar=='+'&&plus==1){
                _return._num = 0;
                _return.is_num = false;
                _return._err = NO_ERR;
                return _return;
            }else{
                _return._num = 0;
                _return.is_num = false;
                _return._err = NO_ERR;
                return _return;
            }
        }else{
            if(i==0){
                _return._num =cchar-'0';
            }else{
                if(pointplace){
                    _return._num+= (cchar-'0')/pow(10,pointplace);
                    pointplace+=1;
                }else{
                    _return._num*=10;
                    _return._num+= (cchar-'0');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    _return._num*=minus;
    return _return;
    
}

sstrfunc ssubstr(sstring _str,int _pos,size_t _len){
    //dont store anything make null return value
    sstrfunc _null;
    
    //is global max char limit corrupted??
    //returning null means error was caught!
    if(isGMCLCorrupt()){
        //gmcl is corrupt! errcode: #defined in sstring.h
        _null._err = GMCL_CORRUPT;
        return _null;
    }
    if(_pos<0){
        _null._err = INVALID_ARGS;
        return _null;
    }
    if(sstrlen(_str)>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT||_pos>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT||_len>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT){
        _null._err = GMCL_ERR;
        return _null;
    }
    
    if(_pos>=sstrlen(_str)||_pos<0||_len>=sstrlen(_str)||_len<0){
        _null._err = INVALID_ARGS;
        return _null;
    }
    
    sstrfunc _ret;
    
    _ret._err = NO_ERR;
    strncpy(_ret._str,_str+_pos,_len);
    _ret._str[_len] = '\0';
    return _ret;
    
}

sstrfunc sstrappend(sstring _var1,sstring _var2){
    //dont store anything make null return value
    sstrfunc _null;
    
    //is global max char limit corrupted??
    //returning null means error was caught!
    if(isGMCLCorrupt()){
        //gmcl is corrupt! errcode: #defined in sstring.h
        _null._err = GMCL_CORRUPT;
        return _null;
    }
    
    
    if(sstrlen(_var1)+sstrlen(_var2)>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT){
        _null._err = GMCL_ERR;
        return _null;
    }
    //use of string.h functions -> far easier than my previous headscratching!
    char _ret1[sstrlen(_var1)+sstrlen(_var2)];
    strcpy(_ret1,_var1);
    strcat(_ret1,_var2);
    sstrfunc _ret;
    //no errors :D
    _ret._err = NO_ERR;
    strcpy(_ret._str,_ret1);
    return _ret;
}

void nullify(char * _Buff,int _count){
    if(isGMCLCorrupt()){
        exit(GMCL_CORRUPT);
    }else if(_count>GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT+1){
        exit(GMCL_ERR);
    }else{
        for(int i=0;i<_count+1;i++){
            _Buff[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
}

sstrfunc sstrinput(){
    //dont store anything make null return value
    sstrfunc _null;
    //is global max char limit corrupted??
    //returning null means error was caught!
    if(isGMCLCorrupt()){
        _null._err = GMCL_CORRUPT;
        return _null;
    }
    char _tmp[GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT];
    //fgets for safety :)
    fgets(_tmp,GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT,stdin);
    sstrfunc _ret;
    //ret._str is array upto GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT
    //also tmp is array upto GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT
    //so its safe :) to use strcpy same as strncpy
    strcpy(_ret._str,_tmp);
    //'\n' avoided
    _ret._str[strlen(_tmp)-1] = '\0';
    _ret._err = NO_ERR;
    return _ret;
}

sstrfunc sstrinputpass(sstring show){
    //dont store anything make null return value
    sstrfunc _null;
    //is global max char limit corrupted??
    //returning null means error was caught!
    if(isGMCLCorrupt()){
        _null._err = GMCL_CORRUPT;
        return _null;
    }
    char _tmp[GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT];
    //nullify string [if i dont use this WiErD things happen]
    nullify(_tmp,GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT+1);
    char tmpchar;
    int done=0;
    //until a certain char has not been pressed
    while(1>0){
        //take chars only upto global max char limit
        if(done>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT-1){
            break;
        }
        tmpchar = getch();
        if(tmpchar=='\r'){
            break;
        }else if(tmpchar=='\b'){
            if(strlen(_tmp)>0){
                _tmp[strlen(_tmp)-1] = '\0';
                for(int i=0;i<sstrlen(show);i++){
                    printf("\b");
                }
                for(int i=0;i<sstrlen(show);i++){
                    printf(" ");
                }
                for(int i=0;i<sstrlen(show);i++){
                    printf("\b");
                }
            }
        }else{
            _tmp[strlen(_tmp)]=tmpchar;
            printf(show);
        
        done+=1;}
    }
    //print newline buffer
    printf("\n");
    
    sstrfunc _ret;
    //ret._str is array upto GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT
    //also tmp is array upto GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT
    //so its safe :) to use strcpy same as strncpy
    strcpy(_ret._str,_tmp);
    //no errors
    _ret._err = NO_ERR;
    return _ret;
}

sstrfunc ssetchar(sstring _str,ssize_t _pos,char _ch){
    sstrfunc _null;
    //is global max char limit corrupted??
    //returning null means error was caught!
    if(isGMCLCorrupt()){
        _null._err = GMCL_CORRUPT;
        return _null;
    }

    sstrfunc _ret;
    if(sstrlen(_str)>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT){
        _null._err = GMCL_ERR;
        return _null;
    }
    if(_pos>=sstrlen(_str)||_pos<0){
        _null._err = INVALID_ARGS;
        return _null;
    }
    strcpy(_ret._str,_str);
    _ret._str[_pos] = _ch;
    _ret._err = NO_ERR;

    return _ret;
}

void showerrs(){
    printf("\n---- ERRORS Corresponding to their codes ----\n");
    printf("%d :- GMCL [global max char limit] is corrupted\n",GMCL_CORRUPT);
    printf("%d :- INVALID ARGS [the provided arguments are invalid]\n",INVALID_ARGS);
    printf("%d :- GMCL_ERR [provided variable has length greater than GMCL]\n",GMCL_ERR);
    printf("Other :- Unknown Error - Not Known Errors \n");
    printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
}


charfunc sgetchar(sstring _str,ssize_t _pos){
    charfunc _null;
    //is global max char limit corrupted??
    if(isGMCLCorrupt()){
        _null._err = GMCL_CORRUPT;
        return _null;
    }
    // condition checking which are likely make error after
    if(sstrlen(_str)>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT){
        _null._err = GMCL_ERR;
        return _null;
    }
    
    if(_pos>=sstrlen(_str)||_pos<0||sstrlen(_str)<0){
        _null._err = INVALID_ARGS;
        return _null;
    }   
    charfunc chr;
    chr._char = _str[_pos];
    chr._err = NO_ERR;
    return chr;
}

//if the length of string is in size_t
//and charachters in it can also be beyond int who knows!
//used ssize_t to support returning negative numbers, i.e -> -1 and errors

//init is the place to start finding
ssize_t sstrfind(size_t init,sstring _str,sstring _find){
    size_t _len1 = sstrlen(_str);
    size_t _len2 = sstrlen(_find);
    size_t matching = 0;
    
    //is global max char limit corrupted??
    if(isGMCLCorrupt()){
        return GMCL_CORRUPT;
    }
    
    if(sstrlen(_str)>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT||sstrlen(_find)>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT){
        return GMCL_ERR;
    }
    
    //some weird conditions check [user, are u fooling the function ?]
    if(_len2>_len1||init<0||init>_len1-1){
        return INVALID_ARGS;
    }
    
    //security check
    if(_len1>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT||_len2>=GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT){
        return GMCL_ERR;
    }
    
    if(_len1==0||_len2==0){
        //obviously it wont be found if the string itself is null or the tobefound string is null
        return -1;
    }
    
    //the main finder -by myself
    for(size_t i=init;i<_len1+1;i++){
        if(_str[i]==_find[0]){
            for(int z=0;z<_len2+1;z++){
                if(matching==_len2){
                    return i;
                }
                else if(_str[i+z]==_find[z]){
                    matching+=1;
                }
                else{
                    matching=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

example-usage.c

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include "sstring.h"
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/*
Example usage of sstring.h functions
initially we dont need to include stdlib.h or string.h
But are included for c-style arr conversion showcase & for exit() functions inside here
*/

//User can handle errors in their **Own** Way

void ErrCheck(sstrfuncerr _str){
    if(_str._err!=NO_ERR){
        printf("\n--- Error %d ---",_str._err);
        showerrs();
        //terminate the program upon error
        //again user can do anything like return value and etc.
        exit(_str._err);
    }   
}

void ErrCodeCheck(int _code){
    if(_code<NO_ERR){
        printf("\n--- Error %d ---",_code);
        showerrs();
        //terminate the program upon error
        //again user can do anything like return value and etc.
        exit(_code);
    }
}

void GenerateErr(int _code){
    if(_code!=NO_ERR){
        printf("\n--- Error %d ---",_code);
        showerrs();
        exit(_code);
    }
}

int main(){
    //---------------- Simplicity Showcase -------------------
    
    sstring a;
    a = "This is a sample string!";
    printf("Sample: %s \n\n",a);
    
    // ----------------- Functions ShowCase -------------------
    
    //all functions of sstring have error checking methods!
    //create an error checking variable
    sstrfuncerr var;
    
    
    // -=-=- Sstrinput() -=-=-
    // No other scanf() or gets() support sstring so, specially sstrinput() for sstrings!
    printf("Sstrinput: ");
    var = sstrinput();
    
    //errcheck
    ErrCheck(var);
    a = var._str;
    
    //-=-=- Sstrlen() -=-=-
    // strlen() from string.h also can do this but added as a support for sstrings!
    printf("Length of a: %d\n\n",sstrlen(a)); // Or printf("Length of a: %d\n\n",strlen(a)); <- from string.h same thing!
    
    //-=-=- Sstrfind() -=-=-
    //lets find space
    int check;
    check = sstrfind(0,a," ");
    
    //errcheck
    //default err check
    ErrCodeCheck(check);
    //unknown err check
    if(check>sstrlen(a)&&check!=-1){
        GenerateErr(check);
    }
    
    if(check==-1){
        printf("Space not found!\n");
    }else{
        printf("Space found at %d charachter!\n",check);
    }
    
    
    
    //-=-=- Ssubstr() -=-=-
    var = ssubstr(a,0,sstrlen(a)-2);
    
    //errcheck
    ErrCheck(var);
    a = var._str;
    
    printf("Without having last two chars : %s\n",a);
    
    //Inputting passwords so easy!
    printf("\nEnter Password: ");
    var = sstrinputpass("*");
    
    //errcheck
    ErrCheck(var);
    
    a = var._str;
    printf("Shh! Your password is : \"%s\"\n",a); 
    
    //Converting to number
    printf("\nEnter a num: ");
    var = sstrinput();
    
    //errcheck
    ErrCheck(var);
    a = var._str;
    
    double num;
    sstrnum ret_num;
    
    //main conversion works on float, double or int values all negative or positive or '+' in front!
    //also can tell if the given string is number or not
    //also has error checking support!
    ret_num = sstr2num(a);
    
    //error check
    if(ret_num._err!=NO_ERR){
        
        GenerateErr(ret_num._err);

    //if not a number
    }else if(ret_num.is_num==false){
        
        printf("You didnt enter a number!");

    //if a number
    }else if(ret_num.is_num==true){
        num = ret_num._num;
        printf("You entered: %f\n",num);
    }
    
    //-=-=- Conversion from array type to sstring and vice-versa -=-=-
    
    char arr_type_str[GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT];
    sstring sstr_type_str;
    int _errcheck;
    
    //first sstring to arr type strings
    
    //fill up sstring
    sstr_type_str = "If you see this, Sstr2Arr conversion success done!";
    //convert
    _errcheck = sstr2cstr(sstr_type_str,arr_type_str,GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT);
    //error check
    ErrCodeCheck(_errcheck);
    //display
    printf("\nSstr 2 Arr: %s\n",arr_type_str);
    
    //Now arr type strings to sstrings!
    
    //first lets nullify our string [previously used]
    nullify(arr_type_str,sstrlen(arr_type_str));
    //fill up array type string
    strcpy(arr_type_str,"If you see this, Arr2Sstr conversion success done!");
    //errcheck first
    ErrCheck(cstr2sstr(arr_type_str));
    //convert
    sstr_type_str = cstr2sstr(arr_type_str)._str;
    //display
    printf("Arr 2 Sstr: %s\n",sstr_type_str);   
}
```

Comment: Why `_` begins so many `struct` member names?

Comment: @chux its meant to be internal so `_` is used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> conversion from c-style array strings to sstrings and vice-versa is now easily possible through sstr2cstr() and cstr2sstr() functions!

Yes possible, but inefficient.

`cstr2sstr()` performs O(GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT) operations even when the C string is much shorter.  This occurs in `return _ret;`

Within `cstr2sstr()` is the curious `strncpy(_ret._str,_Buff,strlen(_Buff));` rather than with simple `memcpy(_ret._str, _Buff, strlen(_Buff));` of which code could also use the prior `strlen(_Buff)` and save that result to avoid another expensive `strlen()` call.  A good compile *may* do that for you.

**Bug 1**

Consider `nullify()` zeros `GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT+2` elements of `_tmp[]` - off by 2!

```
char _tmp[GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT];
nullify(_tmp,GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT+1);

void nullify(char * _Buff,int _count){
  ...
    for(int i=0;i<_count+1;i++){
        _Buff[i] = '\0';
    }
```

**Bug 2**

`fgets(_tmp,GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT,stdin);` does not have the return value checked, so following code lacks knowing if `_tmp` is in fact a *string*.

**Bug 3**

Wrong printf specifier for `size_t` --> undefined behavior.

```
// printf("Length of a: %d\n\n",sstrlen(a));
printf("Length of a: %zu\n\n", sstrlen(a));
```

Also with code like `for(int i=0;i<sstrlen(show);i++){`, a well enabled compiler would have warned.

This, not fully using your compiler's warnings is the biggest mistake.

**Underestimating FP**

"conversion from string to number [double/float/int] type is easily possible ..."

I look forward to seeing that *easy* code.  I suspect it will have unexpected weaknesses.

**Compile Error Check**

The `isGMCLCorrupt()` test deserves to be a `_Static_assert()` compile time test.

**Missing use of `const`**

`const` allows greater optimization and wider use.

```
// sstrfunc cstr2sstr(char * _Buff);
sstrfunc cstr2sstr(const char * _Buff);
```

**Large arrays for C strings**

`sstr2cstr()` obliges the destination C string to be sized `GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT`, yet a C string ends with the first *null character*.  Very inefficient.

**Namespace**

The defines, types and functions  of `sstring.h` are all over the place. Consider a common prefix to locate them lexicographically.

**Documentation**

`sstring.h` deserves documentation to high-light overall usage and function particulars.  Users should not need access to `sstring.c` to discern general function usage.

**Design**

I find code passing around the large `sstrfunc` objects and requiring large string arrays as wholly inefficient and recommend a new design.

Comment: Bug - 1 : every function checks if the specified strings length is [greater or equal] and if true terminates the process with returning error. so doing GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT + 1 in the loop wouldn't cause any bugs. Bug - 2 : Even if the user presses enter without writing any charachters no bugs are found . errors occur if you try to get substr of it because its a null string. Bug - 3: Yeah i understand that but thats located in example-usage.c not in the header files or functions. so the mistake is in example file!

Comment: Underestimating fp : The function returns a typedef of strnum. the strnum contains : bool is_num , int _err, double _num. As far as i know, converting from double type to float type or int type doesn't generate any issue. Compile error check : I am new to c and have this code as my own project. it would be thankful if you provided _how_ could i do that!. Missing use of const : Yeah but i dont think without using it would generate issue. Namespace & Design: please furthermore illustrate what are you trying to say and provide a little bit of example. :)

Comment: @Pear Let us review bug #1: `_tmp` is array 400.  Code calls `nullify(_tmp,401);`.  That function iterates 402 times with `for(int i=0;i<402;i++){ _Buff[i] = '\0';`.  This overruns `_tmp[]`.

Comment: @Pear Bug 2: `fgets()` is called yet there is _no_ input - not even a `'\n'` (I am not talking about the "user presses enter without writing any characters"), but end-of-of-file.  `stdin` is closed.  In that case, `_tmp[]` remains indefinite and `strcpy(_ret._str,_tmp);` is UB.  You have not seen this bug due to not testing for immediate end-of-file (nor the rare input input error).

Comment: @Pear Did not see `sstrnum sstr2num(sstring _str)` earlier.  There code compounds small (and some large) errors with each `_return._num+= (cchar-'0')/pow(10,pointplace);` and `_return._num*=10;` as the math result is not always exact.  String to FP is in itself a _very_ challenging coding task to do well.  This code does OK, yet has precision trouble over the `double` range and overflow trouble near `DBL_MAX, DBL_TRUE_MIN`.  The usual solution is to some extended precision and range.  For now, use `strtod()` if a high quality result is needed.
 `

Comment: @Pear Namespace detail:  Rather than `NO_ERR, charfunc, nullify, sgetchar` surprisingly originating in `sstring.h`, consider  `SSTR_NO_ERR, sstr_charfunc, sstr_nullify, sstr_getchar`  in `sstr.h`.  Keep in mind  `sstring.h` may be including with dozens of other `*.h` files and knowing where a generic name like `NO_ERR` originates is important.

Comment: @Pear Re `const`.  Try `const char *num = "123"; cstr2sstr(num);`

Comment: Very very much thanx for reviewing my code and providing feedbacks! all mentioned bugs are being removed and feedbacks are being implemented! -by myself of course!

Comment: @Pear Type `sstrfunc` deserves a design review.  Recommend to add a `.length` member to keep track of how much of `._str[]` is used.  Yet the really question is do you want to have a fixed size (I suspect you do) or a dynamic size (more useful but many more headaches).  "Strings" in C are tricky - no matter what you choose.

Comment: @Pear Hope for a reply to [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269720/user-friendly-string-struct-and-utility-function-upated-version/269747?noredirect=1#comment532274_269720)/

Comment: I want the strings to be dynamic. however the functions dont handle it so well so i have set the  maximum limit to a functions return of string value is GLOBAL_MAX_CHAR_LIMIT. unless you use any of the functions, the string has no limit to itself

Comment: And hey, sstr2cstr() function doesn't oblige the destination string to be sized `GLOBAL MAX CHAR LIMIT`. it takes 3 parameters sstr2cstr(thesstring,thecstring,_upto). `_upto` is the amount upto which you have sized your variable. even if the sstring size is greater than _upto, string greater than _upto will not be entered into the thecstring making it safe as i have used strncpy()

Comment: thanx for the feedback for sstrfunc! trying it now! also i have added replace() function also improving and fixing the bugs in the new version. [not included here]

Comment: @Pear "making it safe as i have used strncpy()" --> the end result in `char * _Cstr` is then certainly not always a _string_ as `strncpy()` does not always form a _string_.  This reduces the safety of following code assuming a _string_ was formed.  Recall, in C, a _string_ **always** contains a _null character_, else it is not a _string_.

Comment: the user could check for that value in the code itself. no worries because *_Cstr is the variable which has to be assigned!

Answer (score 0):

don't use conio.h  That is a microsoft invention that is not portable

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c" -o "untitled.o" 

untitled.c:36:42: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
   36 | int sstr2cstr(sstring _sstr,char * _Cstr,size_t _upto);
      |                                          ^~~~~~
untitled.c:4:1: note: ‘size_t’ is defined in header ‘<stddef.h>’; did you forget to ‘#include <stddef.h>’?
    3 | #include<stdbool.h>
  +++ |+#include <stddef.h>
    4 | #define SSTRING_H_DEFINED
untitled.c:39:1: error: unknown type name ‘ssize_t’
   39 | ssize_t sstrfind(size_t init,sstring _str,sstring _find);
      | ^~~~~~~
untitled.c:39:18: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
   39 | ssize_t sstrfind(size_t init,sstring _str,sstring _find);
      |                  ^~~~~~
untitled.c:39:18: note: ‘size_t’ is defined in header ‘<stddef.h>’; did you forget to ‘#include <stddef.h>’?
untitled.c:40:1: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
   40 | size_t sstrlen(sstring _str);
      | ^~~~~~
untitled.c:40:1: note: ‘size_t’ is defined in header ‘<stddef.h>’; did you forget to ‘#include <stddef.h>’?
untitled.c:41:32: error: unknown type name ‘ssize_t’
   41 | sstrfunc ssetchar(sstring _str,ssize_t _pos,char _ch);
      |                                ^~~~~~~
untitled.c:42:40: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
   42 | sstrfunc ssubstr(sstring _str,int _pos,size_t _len);
      |                                        ^~~~~~
untitled.c:42:40: note: ‘size_t’ is defined in header ‘<stddef.h>’; did you forget to ‘#include <stddef.h>’?
untitled.c:43:32: error: unknown type name ‘ssize_t’
   43 | charfunc sgetchar(sstring _str,ssize_t _pos);
      |                                ^~~~~~~
untitled.c:72:8: error: conflicting types for ‘sstrlen’
   72 | size_t sstrlen(sstring _str){
      |        ^~~~~~~
untitled.c:40:8: note: previous declaration of ‘sstrlen’ was here
   40 | size_t sstrlen(sstring _str);
      |        ^~~~~~~
untitled.c: In function ‘sstr2cstr’:
untitled.c:112:19: warning: conversion from ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} to ‘int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
  112 |     nullify(_Cstr,_upto);
      |                   ^~~~~
untitled.c: In function ‘sstr2num’:
untitled.c:149:18: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  149 |     for(int i=0;i<sstrlen(_str);i++){
      |                  ^
untitled.c: In function ‘ssubstr’:
untitled.c:219:12: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  219 |     if(_pos>=sstrlen(_str)||_pos<0||_len>=sstrlen(_str)||_len<0){
      |            ^~
untitled.c:219:62: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtype-limits]
  219 |     if(_pos>=sstrlen(_str)||_pos<0||_len>=sstrlen(_str)||_len<0){
      |                                                              ^
untitled.c: In function ‘nullify’:
untitled.c:266:11: error: unknown type name ‘Compilation’
  266 |     }else{Compilation failed.
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
untitled.c:266:29: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
  266 |     }else{Compilation failed.
      |                             ^
untitled.c:267:21: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  267 |         for(int i=0;i<_count+1;i++){
      |                     ^
untitled.c:267:21: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
untitled.c:267:35: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
  267 |         for(int i=0;i<_count+1;i++){
      |                                   ^
      |                                   ;
untitled.c:267:35: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
untitled.c:261:21: warning: parameter ‘_Buff’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
  261 | void nullify(char * _Buff,int _count){
      |              ~~~~~~~^~~~~
untitled.c: In function ‘sstrinputpass’:
untitled.c:316:19: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getch’; did you mean ‘getc’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  316 |         tmpchar = getch();
      |                   ^~~~~
      |                   getc
untitled.c:316:19: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char’ may change value [-Wconversion]
untitled.c:322:30: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  322 |                 for(int i=0;i<sstrlen(show);i++){
      |                              ^
untitled.c:325:30: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  325 |                 for(int i=0;i<sstrlen(show);i++){
      |                              ^
untitled.c:328:30: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  328 |                 for(int i=0;i<sstrlen(show);i++){
      |                              ^
untitled.c:334:13: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  334 |             printf(show);
      |             ^~~~~~
untitled.c: In function ‘ssetchar’:
untitled.c:365:12: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘ssize_t’ {aka ‘long int’} and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  365 |     if(_pos>=sstrlen(_str)||_pos<0){
      |            ^~
untitled.c: In function ‘sgetchar’:
untitled.c:399:12: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘ssize_t’ {aka ‘long int’} and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  399 |     if(_pos>=sstrlen(_str)||_pos<0||sstrlen(_str)<0){
      |            ^~
untitled.c:399:50: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtype-limits]
  399 |     if(_pos>=sstrlen(_str)||_pos<0||sstrlen(_str)<0){
      |                                                  ^
untitled.c: In function ‘sstrfind’:
untitled.c:429:25: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtype-limits]
  429 |     if(_len2>_len1||init<0||init>_len1-1){
      |                         ^
untitled.c:446:26: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  446 |             for(int z=0;z<_len2+1;z++){
      |                          ^
untitled.c:448:28: warning: conversion to ‘ssize_t’ {aka ‘long int’} from ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
  448 |                     return i;
      |                            ^
untitled.c:450:31: warning: conversion to ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
  450 |                 else if(_str[i+z]==_find[z]){
      |                               ^
untitled.c: At top level:
untitled.c:464:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘-’ token
  464 | gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c" -o "untitled.o" (in directory: /home/richard/Documents/forum)
      |     ^
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: i have used conio.h for getch() function. Also did u include the header file?

Comment: user3629249, "don't use conio.h That is a microsoft invention" --> Sure MS invented it?  I suspect they mimicked some prior art.  I do agree with the idea of avoiding non-standard functions, especially when `getc()` would suffice here.

Comment: I placed your header file first,  The result is posted in my answer